# How to organize rails integration/feature specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, capybara

For the controllers, I tested each action like:

```
describe PostsController do
  describe "GET #new"
  describe "GET #edit"
  describe "DELETE #destroy"
  ...
```

How do I organize my integration/feature test? Following the controller structure or user stories or something else? I am using Capybara.

Comment: that depends, i usually end up grouping them by topic and then by functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I first organize it based on actions. Then within each action I organize my tests between good users and bad users. I'm sure someone will get more in depth, but that's my two cents.

Good user - An user who does everything right, putting correct information into forms, etc.

Bad user - A potential hacker, or someone who simply inserts bad information into your website.

Answer (score 0):

When using Capybara, it's usually desirable to create one file per user story, since that will make it easier to reuse any background setup.

It's usually beneficial to keep them small (no more than 3 or 4 `scenario` blocks), otherwise they can be hard to follow.

If you need a way to organize your test code so that you don't couple integration tests with the UI, you can try using [**Capybara Test Helpers**](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/), which allows you to encapsulate interactions with components and pages.